Is "Since $f(x)\cdot I$ may also be regarded as a scalar matrix whose diagonal elements are the polynomials $f(x)$," necessary? (MacDuffee's book)
I am reading "Vectors and Matrices" by Cyrus Colton MacDuffee.
Let $R$ be a ring with unit element $1$. (We don't assume that $R$ is commutative.)
Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n\in R[x]$.
We define $f_L(c)=a_0+a_1c+\cdots+a_nc^n$ for $c\in R$.
We define $f_R(c)=a_0+ca_1+\cdots+c^na_n$ for $c\in R$.

Theorem 36. Let $R$ be a ring with unit element, and let $R[x]$ be its polynomial domain. Let $f(x)\cdot g(x)=h(x)$ in $R[x]$. If $g_L(c)=0$ in $R$, then $h_L(c)=0$. If $f_R(c)=0$ in $R$, then $h_R(c)=0$.

In the following sentences, the author wrote the following sentence:

Since $f(x)\cdot I$ may also be regarded as a scalar matrix whose diagonal elements are the polynomials $f(x)$, it follows from $f(A)\cdot I=0$ that $f(A)=0$.

I cannot understand this sentence.
I cannot understand what the author wants to say.
Is "Since $f(x)\cdot I$ may also be regarded as a scalar matrix whose diagonal elements are the polynomials $f(x)$," necessary?
Since $I$ is the identity matrix, $f(A)\cdot I=f(A)$.
And by the author's argument, $f(A)\cdot I=0$.
So, $f(A)=0$.


I'm not quite sure, but I think he is saying that $f(A) \cdot I$ is a matrix, whose coefficients are also matrices. Thus, having $f(A)$ in the diagonal, we can identify with the $0$ matrix to deduce $f(A) = 0$ (where this $0$ matrix is smaller). I'm just not convinced that replacing $x$ by $A$ is legal.

@Nolord thank you very much for your answer.

This is a poor notation in the author’s otherwise very clear proof. He shouldn’t write $f(A)\cdot I$. What he meant is actually this: let $f(x)=\sum_kc_kx^k$. If we identify $f(x)I =\left(\sum_kc_kx^k\right)I$ (a matrix with polynomial coefficients) with $H(x)=\sum_k(c_kI)x^k$ (a polynomial with matrix coefficients), then $H_L(A) =\sum_k(c_kI)A^k=\sum_kc_kA^k=f(A)$.
Now, as $\operatorname{adj}(Ix-A)(Ix-A)=H(x)$, we have $H_L(A)=0$. Therefore $f(A)=0$.

user1551, thank you very much for your answer!
